# puppet - unexpected result from 'each' in a custom function

Tags: ruby, function, puppet

I have a simple function which takes a JSON and 'does something' with it. The main part works good BUT the function returns not only what I want but additionally the result of *.each* loop!

The code:

```
  module Puppet::Parser::Functions
    newfunction(:mlh, :type => :rvalue) do |args|

    lvm_default_hash    = args[0]
    lvm_additional_hash = args[1]

    if lvm_additional_hash.keys.length == 1
      if lvm_additional_hash.keys.include? 'logical_volumes'
        # do stuff - we have only 'logical_volumes'
        lvm_default_hash.keys.each do |key|

          pv_array       = Hash['physical_volumes' => lvm_default_hash[key]['physical_volumes']]
          lv_hash        = lvm_default_hash[key]['logical_volumes']
          new_lv_hash    = lvm_additional_hash['logical_volumes']
          merged_lv_hash = Hash['logical_volumes' => lv_hash.merge(new_lv_hash)]

          # this is what I want to return to init.pp
          puts Hash[key => pv_array.merge(merged_lv_hash)]

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Variables in the *init.pp* are:

```
$default_volume_groups = {
'sys' => {
  'physical_volumes' => [
    '/dev/sda2',
  ],
  'logical_volumes' => {
    'root'   => {'size' => '4G'},
    'swap'   => {'size' => '256M'},
    'var'    => {'size' => '8G'},
    'docker' => {'size' => '16G'},
  },
},
```

}

and the second argument from a hieradata:

```
modified_volume_groups:
logical_volumes:
  cloud_log:
    size: '16G'
```

In the *init.pp* I have something like this to test it:

```
notice(mlh($default_volume_groups, $modified_volume_groups))
```

which gives me a result:

```
syslogical_volumesvarsize8Gdockersize16Gcloud_logsize16Gswapsize256Mrootsize4Gphysical_volumes/dev/sda2
Notice: Scope(Class[Ops_lvm]): sys
```

The "long" part before the Notice is the proper result from the *puts* but the *Notice: Scope(): sys* is this what **I do not want to**!
I know that this is the result of this *each* loop over the **default_volumes_groups**:

```
lvm_default_hash.keys.each do |key|
  # some stuff
end
```

How to block of this unwanted result? It blows my puppet's logic because my *init.pp* sees this *sys* and not what I want.

Does someone knows how to handle such problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the extra text you see printed is not part of your function's return value at all.  It looks like debug output describing the call to `notice()`, as opposed to being any part of the value presented to `notice()` for it to print.

Comment: Thank you but how it is happen that my function returns two values - one from the _puts_ and one from the _each_ loop over the default value?

Answer (score 1):

I found how to handle this problem but maybe someone could explain me why it works in this way :)

This does not work (short version):

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:mlh, :type => :rvalue) do |args|

    lvm_default_hash    = args[0]
    lvm_additional_hash = args[1]

    if lvm_additional_hash.keys.length == 1
      if lvm_additional_hash.keys.include? 'logical_volumes'
        lvm_default_hash.keys.each do |key|

          pv_array       = Hash['physical_volumes' => lvm_default_hash[key]['physical_volumes']]
          lv_hash        = lvm_default_hash[key]['logical_volumes']
          new_lv_hash    = lvm_additional_hash['logical_volumes']
          merged_lv_hash = Hash['logical_volumes' => lv_hash.merge(new_lv_hash)]

          puts Hash[key => pv_array.merge(merged_lv_hash)]

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but this works:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:mlh, :type => :rvalue) do |args|

    lvm_default_hash    = args[0]
    lvm_additional_hash = args[1]

  # empty Hash
    hash_to_return = {}

    if lvm_additional_hash.keys.length == 1
      if lvm_additional_hash.keys.include? 'logical_volumes'
        lvm_default_hash.keys.each do |key|

          pv_array       = Hash['physical_volumes' => lvm_default_hash[key]['physical_volumes']]
          lv_hash        = lvm_default_hash[key]['logical_volumes']
          new_lv_hash    = lvm_additional_hash['logical_volumes']
          merged_lv_hash = Hash['logical_volumes' => lv_hash.merge(new_lv_hash)]

        # assigned value in the 'each' loop we want to return to puppet
          hash_to_return = Hash[key => pv_array.merge(merged_lv_hash)]

        end

      # returned Hash - instead of previous 'puts'
        return hash_to_return

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I have what I need!

```
Notice: Scope(Class[Ops_lvm]): sysphysical_volumes/de
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got it -- the first one doesn't work because in Ruby, the return value of a block or function is the last evaluated statement. In the case of the one that didn't work, the last evaluated statement was the `.each`. As it turns out, `each` evaluates to the enumerable that it was looping through.

A simple example:

```
def foo
  [1, 2, 3].each do |n|
    puts n
  end
end
```

If I were to run this, the return value of the function would be the array:

```
> foo
1
2
3
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

So what you have works, because the last thing evaluated is `return hash_to_return`. You could even just go `hash_to_return` and it'd work.

If you wanted to get rid of the `return` and clean that up a little bit (and if you're using Ruby 1.9 or above), you could replace your `each` line with:

`lvm_default_hash.keys.each_with_object({}) do |key, hash_to_return|`

This is because `each_with_object` evaluates to the "object" (in this case the empty hash passed into the method, and referred to as `hash_to_return` in the block params). If you do this you can remove the `return` as well as the initialization `hash_to_return = {}`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your custom function has rvalue type which means it needs to return value. If you don't specify `return <something>` by default, your last statement is implicitly your return.
In the example above, first one that does not work correctly, has last statement inside each block:

```
puts Hash[key => pv_array.merge(merged_lv_hash)]
```

Your second example is correct simply because you set value for hash_to_return in each block and then "return" it outside of each block. Not sure if this is the behavior you want since last assigned hash value (in last loop inside each block) will be the one that will be returned from this function.

Comment: This is related to the @kamh comment that starts with:
I found how to handle this problem but maybe someone could explain me why it works in this way :)